# UITableView not pulling JSON in correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, json, uitableview, restkit

**EDIT-
Solved:**
I added a Model for "Feed" which took care of the mapping problem I was having.  Thanks!

I want to display all of the "Headline" in `UITableView` rows, but I'm getting a crash:

WebListViewController.m -

```
@interface WebListViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *headlinesNow;

@end

@implementation WebListViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize headlinesNow;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *lAbbreviation = [defaults objectForKey:@"lAbbreviation1"];
    NSString *tID = [defaults objectForKey:@"tId1"];

 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/now/?l=%@&t=%@&apikey=5xxxxxxxx", lAbbreviation, tID];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader)  {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {

headlinesNow = objects;

[_tableView reloadData];

[loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Headline mapping] forKeyPath:@"feed.headline"];
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
            NSLog(@"BodyAsString: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        };
    }];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return headlinesNow.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Headline *headlineLocal = [headlinesNow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", headlineLocal.headline];
    cell.textLabel.text = headlineText;
    return cell;
}
```

Headline.h

```
@interface Headline : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *headline;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Links *linksHeadline;
+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
@end
```

Headline.m

```
@implementation Headline
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"headline", @"headline",
         nil];
        [mapping hasOne:@"links" withMapping:[Links mapping]];
    }];
    return objectMapping;
}
@end
```

JSON Response Body -

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-03T22:03:45Z",
    "resultsOffset": 0,
    "status": "success",
    "resultsLimit": 10,
    "breakingNews": [],
    "resultsCount": 341,
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "This is the first headline",
        "lastModified": "2013-05-03T21:33:32Z",
        "premium": false,
        "links": {
            "api": {
```

I'm getting the `NSLog` output for `bodyAsResponse`, but the program is crashing and not filling in the `UITableView`.  I'm obviously not navigating into the JSON correctly? Any ideas?

Appreciate the help, let me know if you need any more code snippets-

**EDIT-**
Crash is: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xe693110> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key headline.'

Comment: Also, better to show your mapping config than table view and empty init method code.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the tip, I added the crash and also the mapping per your suggestion-

Comment: I think your current forKeyPath:@"feed.headline" should just be forKeyPath:@"feed" as that keypath isn't valid for your JSON.

Comment: @Wain I just changed it and get this now: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Headline 0x8248b70> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key links.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is your current `forKeyPath:@"feed.headline"`. It should just be `forKeyPath:@"feed"` as that keypath isn't valid for your JSON. The reason is that `feed` in your JSON is an array so it should map to your `Headline` object, then your mapping definition for that object will be used for the `headline`.

Next issue is the `linksHeadline` attribute and the `[mapping hasOne:@"links" withMapping:[Links mapping]];`. The key names don't match. Change the property name in `Headline` to be `links`.